# url rewriting not working as wanted

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to achieve a clean url that looks like  `http://localhost/slugs/this-is-my-first-slug-post`

but instead I have `http://localhost/slugs/news.php?newsheadline=this-is-my-first-slug-post`

I have an htaccess file with this code but it doesn't seem to work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^[A-Za-z-]+/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    news.php?newsheadline=$1    [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /slugs/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /news\.php\?newsheadline=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ news.php?newsheadline=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but it also doesn't work. Could it be because I am using through my localhost and not on an actual domain?
http://localhost:slugs/news.php?newsheadline=this-is-my-first-slug-post

Comment: The initial url is http://localhost/slugs/index.php

Then I click on the article heading to go to:

http://localhost/slugs/news.php?newsheadline=this-is-my-first-slug-post

The .htaccess is located in the root with the php files

Comment: my page doesn't seem to have the last /
Not sure if that is an issue? I don't know how to make it show up i.e.:
this-is-my-first-slug-post/
Mine doesn't have that slash at the end, it's just this-is-my-first-slug-post
Not sure if that makes a difference?

Comment: Is `/slugs/` a real directory?

Comment: slugs is the root directory or name of my 'domain'. This is running on my local test server, not actually online at a real domain, hence the localhost in front. So, the folder on my local and www folders are called 'slugs'. Inside 'slugs' are my php files like index.php and news.php as well as the .htaccess file

Comment: ok try updated code in `/slugs/.htaccess` and keep these rules before any other rule you may have.

Comment: Excellent! Will this work when I upload to an actual server though?

Comment: It should work if server also have `/slug/` directory, otherwise just comment out `RewriteBase` line.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks so much. Last question if you can help otherwise I will open a new post. Should I insert the title without the dashes or with them? Ie: this-is-my-article

Comment: You can use title with dashes and dashes are totally fine for SEO also